# Order of registering Flask Blueprints

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I ran into a strange issue (maybe not so strange for experienced in flask).

I have a flask application running in the context of Google App Engine's `dev_appserver.py`

I have a blueprint in my flask application

```
# rest_server.py

rest_api = Blueprint('rest_api', __name__)
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(rest_api, url_prefix='/api')  # [1] DOESN'T WORK

@rest_api.route("/")
def hello():
  return "Hello World"

app.register_blueprint(rest_api, url_prefix="/api")  # [2] WORKS AS EXPECTED
```

I have the following in my `app.yaml`

```
-url: "/api/.*"
 script: rest_server.app
```

When I hit `localhost:8080/api/` when I register blueprint at position [1], I get an error saying there is no matching endpoint.

However, when I register bluerpint at [2], any position *after* the decorator, it works.

Is it required to register the blueprint after all the decorators?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's required to register blueprints only after all their routes have been declared, at least if you want to use those routes. (If you don't mind the routes not being available, it doesn't look like there's actually any problem with declaring new routes after registering the blueprint.)

If you want to know why: basically, blueprint url rules are only registered on the application when `Flask.register_blueprint` is called. If you add routes after registering the blueprint, they just get added to the list of things to do when the blueprint is registered (`Blueprint.deferred_functions`), they don't get retroactively added to any existing applications that the blueprint was registered to in the past.

Answer (score -1):

Though you have registered your blueprint, it is not actually registered!
the point is that your application is not aware of existence `rest_server.py`

You have to register it in the same file in which you have the following code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

This should solve your problem.

---

I'd like to show the pattern of using blueprints I use.
(It is useful for a better organization of your code) **:**

**Blueprint Pattern** 

your application can look like this:

```
/yourapplication
    runserver.py
    /application  #your application is a package containing some blueprints!
        __init__.py
        models.py
        /hello   #(blueprint name)
            __init__.py
            views_file1.py
            views_file2.py
```

your `runserver.py` should look like this:

```
# runserver.py

from application import app
app.run()
```

In this example, hello is a package and one of your blueprints:

```
# application/hello/__init__.py
from flask import Blueprint
hello = Blueprint('main', __name__)
# import views of this blueprint:
from application.hello import views_file1, views_file2
```

Import and register your blueprints in `application/__ init__.py`. your  `application/__ init__.py`  should look like this:

```
# application/__init__.py

from flask import Flask
from .hello import hello as hello_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(hello_blueprint)
from application.models import * #your models (classes, or *)
```