# Is it possible to declare a Flask Blueprint in one file but use the decorator for the implementation in another?

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on a Flask project and trying to organize my code by using the Blueprint decorator. Specifically, I want to create a Flask Blueprint in one file and provide the implementation with decorators in a different file. E.g.

**blueprints.py:**

```
from flask import Blueprint
dashboard_blueprint = Blueprint('dashboard', __name__)
```

**dashboard_routes.py:**

```
from .blueprints import dashboard_blueprint

@dashboard_blueprint.route('/hello')
def hello():
    ...
```

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask
from blueprints import dashboard_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(dashboard_blueprint, "/dashboard")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Most examples I've found on the internet would provide the implementation of `def hello` inside `blueprints.py` with decorator applied directly in there. However, I'm about to implement a dashboard with multiple subpages. I don't want to define a blueprint for every subpage, but rather use the generic dashboard Blueprint and implement the routes in every subpage file, e.g. `/dashboard/subpage1`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Your code doesn't work because you are importing the blueprint but never register a route, `dashboard_routes.py` never gets imported/ran. Instead your `app.py` should import from `dashboard_routes`

```py
from flask import Flask
from dashboard_routes import dashboard_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(dashboard_blueprint, "/dashboard")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I'd also recommend taking a look at [nesting blueprints](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/blueprints/#nesting-blueprints). It'll allow you to create subpages without having to add a common prefix, just like `/dashboard`.

Comment: what about this answer that says that you basically cannot add routes after registering the blueprint? 

[https://stackoverflow.com/q/40730312/16911276]

Comment: What about it? The answer is correct. Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: I did. Your approach works only if the implementation that is given under the decorator is imported. i.e. the route defined in `dashboard_routes.py` would only work if some other function defined elsewhere is returned as a result. When writing code directly under the decorator, your approach does not work.

This code works:

`from .blueprints import dashboard_blueprint`
`from .other import some_function`

`@dashboard_blueprint.route('/hello')`
`def hello():`
`return some_function()`